# Investigate correlation conditional on a threshold

Tags: regression, correlation, data-visualization, threshold, conditioning

I have 3 variables in my data set.

(i) My gut feel says variable1 and variable2 are correlated,  only when variable3 >= threshold3. What is the technique I can use to see if this holds true, to statistical significance (simple regression based/machine learning)?

eg. Taking variables in Stock Market, I think stock price move is correlated to Price Momentum over the last 3o minutes, but only when Volatility Index is above a certain threshold.  I do not know the threshold value and also do not know if the statement, that the above correlation is significant only when the threshold is met, holds.  Looking for a technique that I can use to formally investigate.

(ii) The other scenario: My gut feel says variable1 and variable2 are correlated, after variable2 >= threshold2. What would be the technique to investigate this?

eg. Similar to the above example, when the correlation between two variables is significant only when one of the 2 variables is above a threshold in its space, looking to investigate if that is true and also estimate the threshold.

Comment: Can you say anything more about your situation and your data? Do you know the thresholds, or are the thresholds something you need to estimate from your data?

Comment: I am trying to estimate the thresholds, if infact there exists a significant correlation, above the threshold. Say, I take the example of some variables in stock market and think, price is correlated to volume, only when the volatility index is above a certain value, I am trying to estimate if there exists a threshold above which this correlation is significant.

Comment: It's best to edit clarifications into the question rather than post them as a comment. I've tried editing your last comment into the question for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could investigate your data visually with a conditioning plot, in R this is named `coplot`.  There is an example in [Best method to visualize large interaction between two factors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19966/best-method-to-visualize-large-interaction-between-two-factors/20215#20215)  or run `example(coplot)`  within R.

Say your tree variables are $x,y,z$ and you suspect the relationship between $y$ and $x$ depends on the values of $z$. Then you would use the following command in R:

```
coplot(y ~ x | z, data=yourdataframe)
```

assuming your variables are in data frame `yourdataframe`.

Below an example of an conditioning plot produced by R:

[image: example conditioning plot using R swiss dataset]

The R code used was:

```
data(swiss)
with(swiss, coplot(Fertility ~ Education | Agriculture))
```

To read the plot: The order of the subplots is from bottom and from left, so the plot corresponding to the lowest vales of variable `Agriculture` is bottom left. Other examples of `coplot`s can be found here:  [What is the physical significance of cumulative correlation coefficient?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239645/what-is-the-physical-significance-of-cumulative-correlation-coefficient/371412#371412)  and  [Can I analyze or model a conditional correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203494/can-i-analyze-or-model-a-conditional-correlation/368228#368228)

As for your second scenario: Here there is only two variables, so a usual scatterplot will do. You can add some nonparametric smooth to the plot, for a more formal approach see [How to use segmented package to fit a piecewise linear regression with one breakpoint?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20890/how-to-use-segmented-package-to-fit-a-piecewise-linear-regression-with-one-break)  and search this site for the tag [piecewise-linear](/questions/tagged/piecewise-linear).